# Problems with new clean Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, server, system-installation, 16.04, reboot

After installing Ubuntu server 16.04LTS on HP DL360 g7 have some surprising problems. I'm tring to reinstall with different images and boot media, but still have the same result.
After first boot all work like a charm. But if you want to shutdown or restart (by systemctl or sutdown command) system going to shutdown/restart but can't do it correctly. Then I have 2 cases:

1) If you have a lot of patience system will finish do what you want still 7-10 minutes. After that (SIC!) on next boot you will see the GINGER (ubuntu collour) tty1. Which can switch to normal colours after running mc or some commands like < fdisk -l>. All other ttys have normal white colour. Almost all next reboots/shutdowns work correctly(under 5seconds), tty1 still ginger after boot. But sometimes can see timing problem.

2)If you haven't patience and "help" system pressing SysRq combinations or hardware poweroff button you will see (on next boot) normal tty1. And all next reboots/sshutdowns works fine.

P.S. I Use different ISOs, flashdrives/SDs. System was installed on true hardware raid on zeroed MBR partition. During install my choice:
standard utils,
server utils,
LAMP,
SAMBA,
OpenSSH.
I don't use any mouse, keyboard, monitor. Headless server managed by ILO3.

Previous Ubuntu 14.04LTS works like a charm for me on this hardware.

Comment: And I don't  know is it a bug or a feature,  but after boot Ubuntu shows black tty7 by default.

Comment: Instead of commenting, you can edit your question to contain any additional information you wish to add.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. 1) I should not use boot flash creators like unetbootin with server verion 16.04LTS. When I try to install by adding iso image to virtual cdrom (ILO sweet feature) I see another result. OS show visible POST when loading modules. After boot I have normal terminals. **It also resolve bug with default tty7**(now default tty1). On this site I see that other members have the same problem with it. People, try different boot flash creators or don't use them!
But when I try to reboot/shutdown, I still have long time delay. it happens because systemd couldn't normal stop MySQL. Also 'systemctl stop' command not working for MySQL service. So if you KILL this process or uninstall MySQL delay problem will vanished to. So another question will be **"Why systemd couldn't stop MySQL daemon"**